# WPF combobox ItemTemplate does not apply

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a combobox, which is bound to a dictionary of

```
<int, MyObject>
```

by the following code:

```
this.comboBox.ItemsSource= dictionary;
```

MyObject has some public properties, such as Name (string) and Selected (boolean).

In my Xaml I have an ItemTemplate on comboBox:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

When I run the app, I get the combobox filled with [1, MyObject] values.

What I eventually want to do is have a checkbox and a textblock in the ItemTemplate, which will be bound to MyObject.Selected and MyObject.Name. At the moment, I can't even get the datatemplate to display the dictionaty Key value.

Any ideas why the itemtemplate is being ignored? I've tried the full temeplate (stack planel containing a combobox and textblock), that showed the same values at runtime.

cheers.

Comment: I do not remember exactly what property has higher priority but please check DisplayMemberPath property to be null/empty. VS's Output window often gives many hints to binding problems.
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window. Here you can set the  kinds of databinding eventsn shown to you

Comment: The displayMembmerPath value is not set anywhere, I'm guessing that means its null? Or does WPF do some oddness that gives it a default value?

Comment: No, If you do not set it explicitly.

Comment: I think I just found the problem, buried somewhere in the framework code was a style, which was overriding the itemTemplate. cheers for the help!

Comment: Hum.. that is strange cause locally set values have higher priority.

Comment: That's what I thought :/

Comment: And the reality is the Style overriding the local value?? o_O ?

Comment: thats what it looks like, taking the style binding out solved the problem.